# Model of ACL component CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-acl

I want to know how to specify the Model for ACL as my model is Admin and I think it tries to access User Model, don't know why =S

> AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array (
>   [Aro0.model] => User [Aro0.foreign_key] => 2 ) "

Please guys if anyone has any idea how to solver that issue, let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go through these urls in the order they have written.

**Basics:**
http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-AclComponent.html

**Script:**
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-cakephps-access-control-lists/